# Refreshing Table View Efficiently

Tags: python, ios, swift, django, uitableview

I am using Django as my backend and inside my iOS application , I am fetching data through API's. I have a UITableView where I am fetching a list of places which also have a rating value with them. After implementing the refresh control I noticed that whenever I used to refresh, it used to append the new data in the array and created duplicity. I thought of a very simple solution which is that we can actually empty our array when refreshing so that we can avoid duplicity. Is it the most efficient way to do this? I am concerned because right now I have 3 places in my backend which I am trying to fetch and what about when there will be hundreds , will we have any performance impact ?

Comment: You should search for the question there are many similiar questions and answers. https://www.google.com/search?q=uitableview+update+datasource+array+stackoverflow&oq=uitableview+update+datasource+array+stackoverflow Regarding your performance , there is nothing affecting the performance of what you are trying to achieve , however, you should take a look at memory usage of your app, if you load too many objects into multiple arrays across your app, you need to keep eye on how much data/memory your app uses etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply No,** There is no any performance issue that you have been tried also you can assign the new response to your variable without removing the result **just like that:**

```
result = newResult;
```

It is the best way to handle this situation you can see at last of [Google Place API SDK](https://github.com/manGoweb/FTGooglePlacesAPI/blob/master/XcodeProject/FTGooglePlacesAPI/FTGooglePlacesAPIExampleResultsViewController.m) which they implement. 
And this is sure that they do anything after doing all test cases and analysis.

Comment: First of all thank you for clearing out the performance part and I did not get the line that "you can append it without removing" . Actually , if I do like this then if I have two items in array they will become 4?

Comment: So isn't emptying the present array which is holding my object a much better way to do it rather than declaring a new variable and then assigning it the way you have told to be?

Comment: There is nothing declare any new variable I am saying that when you get the response from the backend not remove and append it instead of just assigning it.

Comment: See the line 241 in the Google place api sdk.

Comment: Yup I did go through it and saw the line. Much appreciated.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Yes I did get it

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

> After implementing the refresh control I noticed that whenever I used to refresh, it used to append the new data in the array and created duplicity. I thought of a very simple solution which is that we can actually empty our array when refreshing so that we can avoid duplicity.

When you refresh the data (pull-to-refresh) you should empty `array` of your data and fill it with new data.

> will we have any performance impact?

And if you mean something like "paging" loading, you probably should read around about this big problem. Personally, very like [twitter's post](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines) about implementing timelines.
Also, should be mention that there is no problems with display data on the screen, because the `reloadData()` func reloads only visible cells. `reload/delete/insertRows` also doesn't so heavy operation for UI. So, the only problem of implementation it is all about consistency of you data-on-the-screen and db.

Comment: Currently , I am doing the same as you have told like emptying the array and then appending new data to it and will give a read to the link you provided for the twitters post

Answer (score 1):

I think best approach will be pagination. Fetch like 10 or 20 data in the beginning and save it in an array and load `tableview`. When user starts scrolling the `tableview` in method `willDisplayCell` increase page count and fetch next 10 or 20 data from server and append it in the array.

Comment: You are right and I also had pagination in the mind but I was thinking there might be something which we can do to avoid like removing and appending again. The question arose because in my backend if I just changed the rating of one place , I wanted to see that and for that I will have to empty my array and fetch new data